# Two parametrs in mod_rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have problem with mod_rewrite rule.
I'm trying to get adress:

```
www.site.com/en/page.html
```

from url

```
index.php?page=page&lang=en
```

I've tried a couple of hours and I can not get ... Unfortunately, I do not know at all mod_rewrite ...

Can someone a guiding me to a solution?

-
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure *mod_rewrite* is enabled in your Apache configuration file.
Also, make sure *htaccess* files are allowed (`AllowOverride All` for your document root folder).

Then, put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in document root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)\.html$ /index.php?page=$2&lang=$1 [L]
```

This rule allows you to reach any language/page, for instance:

1. http://domain.com/en/page.html --> `/index.php?page=page&lang=en`
2. http://domain.com/fr/something.html --> `/index.php?page=something&lang=fr`

If you want to restrict `lang` parameter:

For english only

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/([^/]+)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1&lang=en [L]
```

For english and french (as an example)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/([^/]+)\.html$ /index.php?page=$2&lang=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help - exactly is what I meant.
Roughly already beginning to understand what's going on...
From the documentation at hand I can handle it :)

-
Peter

Comment: If my answer helped you then you can validate it in order to mark your question as solved (you should also post your message as a comment below my answer instead of an answer)

Comment: Ok, now I see how it works, I'm new here and not everything was clear to me.